# iTextSharp does not show Unicode symbols on pdf document

Tags: unicode, webforms, itext, html-parsing, symbols

I have a little problem in ASP.NET Webforms I am using iTextSharp to create a pdf document. Everything works great, except the Unicode characters that are not displayed or they appear as question marks. Here is my code, if anyone knows what am I doing wrong I would be very grateful!

```
BaseFont base = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Wingdings.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(base, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var document = new Document())
            {
             HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(document);
             document.NewPage();
             string str = " \u2022 \u2706 ";
             Phrase phrase = new Phrase(str, font);
             document.Add(phrase);
             //and after that I have some other strings which are parsed with parser and that works perfectly
         }}
```

I have tried to parse the phrase with XMLWorkerHelper, but it did not work at all. Also, I have tried to convert the string like this and the symbols appeared as question marks. I have tried to change the font like Wingding2, Wingding3 but it did not work.

```
 byte[] bytestr = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
 string convertstr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytestr);
 Phrase phrase = new Phrase(convertstr, font);
 document.Add(phrase);
```

Also I have tried to enter them like this, but also I've got the same result with the question marks

```
string str = "•✆";
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(str, font);
document.Add(phrase);
```

**EDIT:** I have tried to change the font to Segoe UI Symbol and escape characters like \u260F, but still does not work.

Comment: You create the font using `BaseFont.CP1252` as encoding. Thus, you should not expect that font to contain characters not on code page 1252.

Comment: @k-j those codes work perfectly for the symbols, but if I put them somewhere in a string, all of the string appears like symbols. For example string str = "Phrase  beggins: \x6C  \x26"; appears even the Phrase beggins in symbol characters

Comment: I have tried str = "/F0 Phrase beggins: /F1 \x6C \x26"; but it is not working for me

Comment: Now I understand you, I get what you are telling me to switch the fonts. Thanks for the idea. Just one more question, if I change the Wingdings font to Segoe UI Symbol because I saw that it supports letters and symbols, why Segoe does not want to show the symbols? I tried to escape them like this \u260F

Comment: Thank you so much for these answers. Meanwhile I have noticed that in Segoe escaping with \x173 for example works fine. When I try to escape \x2706 it is not working or \x3EE when it contains letters.